# Print text using black ink on HP Laserjet color printer

Tags: printing, cups, hplip

I have a HP LaserJet CP1025NW (color) printer installed on a Linux Mint 20.1 machine using HPLIP (required plugin installed, version 3.20.11). For some reason, whenever I try to print a document (e.g. PDF, a text file, etc.) with black text inside, the text is *always* printed using the three CMY colors. The result is not as pretty looking as if the text had been printed using the black cartridge only; also, it is a waste of ink.

Notice that if the *same* document is printed via a Windows machine on the *same* printer, I get the expected result of black text printed in pure black.

I could not find any option (neither in CUPS, nor in HPLIP) to adjust this undesired behavior.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found a solution:

1. Uninstall the printer from HPLIP and from the system;
2. Be sure that the following package is installed: `printer-driver-foo2zjs` (I checked from Synpatics);
3. Open http://localhost:631
4. Add printer "HP LaserJet CP 1025nw (Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet CP 1025nw)" from "Discovered Network Printers". Go ahead with installation until the last page with the "Add printer" button;
5. Be sure to select "HP" from the "Make" menu (even if you already see "Hewlett Packard": they are two different "Make" items);
6. Under "Model", select "HP LaserJet Pro CP1025nw Foomatic/foo2zjs-z3 (recommended) (en)" (be sure to find exactly *that* model: you have to scroll down quite a lot);
7. Add the printer.